# How to make the location data such as Latitude Longitude available in an image taken from android device

Tags: android

I am currently working on an android app which is capturing an image and uploading it to S3.
When I upload the image to S3 backend developer says I can not access location (lat/long) from the image
Basically he is telling me to "download the image you uploaded and see in its details:
So how to make lat/long available there?.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please just try this way before you proceed

```
public static void writeFile(File photo, double latitude, double longitude) {
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photo.getCanonicalPath());
    if (exif != null) {
        double latitu = latitude;
        double longitu = longitude;
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, ""+latitu);
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, ""+longitu);
        try {
            exif.saveAttributes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String lati = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
        String longi = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
    }
}


private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        final File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, "");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.toString());
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, ""+latitu);                   exif.saveAttributes();
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            //upload photo..
        }
    }
}

Bitmap sBitmap = null;
sBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(photo), null, options);
FileOutputStream sfOut = new FileOutputStream(photo);
rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, sfOut);
```

Comment: @gpuser can you explain why it is returning null?

Comment: @SanketBhangale, it may be image issue or writing problem, I just shared the way you can update according to your requirement and flow in your way, please check I updated code it may help